# Why is Google font not working?

Tags: css, font-face, google-font-api

I am using Google font from http://www.google.com/webfonts/earlyaccess but it's not working as it suppose to. Any ideas.

I set up a basic version at http://jsfiddle.net/UbDcg/4/ which is not working like it suppose to .

**HTML**

```
 FONT RESOURCE:<br>
 http://www.google.com/webfonts/earlyaccess<br>

<div id="fontTest">
   Lohit font why not working ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/lohitdevanagari.css);    

 body{
      font-family: verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
      font-size:12px;
 }

#fontTest{
     background:#e8e8e8;
     padding:20px;
     margin-top: 20px;
     font-family: 'Lohit Devanagari', serif;
 }
```

Comment: Yea... I just realized that.. but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the font-family as follows:

```
font-family: 'Lohit Devanagari', serif;
```

That's how it is displayed in the Google documentation: http://www.google.com/webfonts/earlyaccess

Answer (score 0):

It is working! You've made a typo the first time, but now it's working.

Try it with

```
<div id="fontTest">
    It's working!<br/>
    सभी मनुष्यों को गौरव और अधिकारों के मामले में जन्मजात स्वतन्त्रता और समानता प्राप्त है। उन्हें बुद्धि और अन्तरात्मा की देन प्राप्त है और परस्पर उन्हें भाईचारे के भाव से बर्ताव करना चाहिये
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/UbDcg/5/

Comment: Thank you for working on it... but I am not understanding the part where it's working! is still showing up in english!!... Isn't that suppose to show in Hindi as well?

Comment: Wait... you mean like an automatic translation? Fonts are only "images" of letters and symbols, you can't convert between languages by only changing the font!

Answer (score 0):

The font in question "Lohit Devanagari" appears to have been removed from the Google site:
http://www.google.com/webfonts/
Try searching that site for "Lohit Devanagari" and you will see it no longer exists.

Answer (score -1):

Adding an !important tag to your css will fix it.

```
#fontTest {font-family: 'Lohit Devanagari', serif !important}
```